# Creating Sections That Are Independent Of Each Other in UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Let's say I have an array with [Apple, Orange, Grape, and Banana] and I want them to each have their own section in a UITableView but each section has the same structure. For example each section allows the user to input the amount and calories for each item in the array. Is there a way to make this possible. I'm a beginner and I'm having difficulties with UITableView.

I'm fairly close and I know I can use func "numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int" with the count of the array for the number of sections I want but if I do one thing in one section it affects all the others. To explain this more clearly I want the user to be able to enter the amount of rows that he/she wants to add. If the user enters 2 in one section it will add 2 rows to every section instead of just that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by creating dictionary and inserting each section data with different array,here name is array.i think this code can help you out.
[image: try this way]

[image: number of sections]

[image: section header]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When reading your code it seems to make a lot of sense however I am using swift so attached is what I have so far out of it. I am using 3 prototype cells and it was kind of hard to follow your cellForRowAtIndexPath function so I created one that was a little bit different. I have error that I don't know how to fix at line 7.

Comment: [1]: http://i.imgur.com/1auMYIP.png [2]: http://i.imgur.com/0RzEXgT.png [3]: http://i.imgur.com/dj7g3Lb.png [4]: http://i.imgur.com/x08rnuO.png [5]: http://i.imgur.com/Qq8Kbv5.png [6]: http://i.imgur.com/9bnDuZF.png

Comment: go to this link and step by step do it, it will work out for swift.http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Answer (score -2):

Uitextfield amount and calories with tag values . u have to take tage values like . strTage=[nstringtag stringwithformat:@"%d%d",indexpath.row+1,indexpath.section+1]; 
Txtfld.tag=[strTage integervalue]; strTage declare should be global as nstring here 11 means section 0 and row 0 and 21 means section 1 and row 0 .you have need to split tag value in didendeding method of text fields and also set delegates u can store your array values in here.

Comment: Where exactly would I put something like this? In the section funcion?

Comment: Txtfld should be in uitableviecell and set the txtfld tag value in cellforrowat index and you have gettext value from tag id and store in array in text field didend delegates method